# Read-only command-line Twitter client

Tags: command-line

There are a bunch of command line Twitter clients, but as I know, all require a Twitter account. I'm interested in a command line Twitter client for read-only activity. Does it exist one?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Twitter/lib/Net/Twitter.pod

Comment: @GillesQuenot, I've tried the example app https://metacpan.org/source/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-4.01043/examples/oauth_desktop.pl. Requires Twitter account (or I'm being dumb).

Comment: `# When no authentication is required:`

Comment: @GillesQuenot, tried: line 24 in oauth_desktop.pl changed to "my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(legacy => 0);" and now the error is <<Can't locate object method "get_authorization_url" via package "Net::Twitter_v4_01043_with__API_REST" at ./oauth_desktop.pl line 32.>>

Comment: @GillesQuenot, full disclosutre: I'm utterly ignorant of OOP and I've been unable to reverse engineer the command-line syntax implemented in the library/oauth_desktop.pl example. AND too dumb to find/understand it if... Maybe it will be better if I try at StackOverflow?